# Find the area of ​the plane region defined by $x^{2/3}+y^{2/3}≤ 1$ , $x≥0$ , $y≥0$ using a change of variables

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates, jacobian, iterated-integrals

> Find the area of ​​the plane region defined by $x^{2/3}+y^{2/3}\leq 1$ , $x\geq 0$ , $y\geq 0$ using the change of variables $x=r\cos^3 \theta$ , $y=r\sin^3 \theta$

The teacher used polar coordinates to express this region, which looks like so:

[image: Looks of the region described]

And went and used $\Omega=\{(r,\theta)\in\mathbb{R}^2:0<r<1,\ 0 <\theta < 2\pi \}$ to describe the region and then used the Jacobian to find the area as so: $$A=\frac{1}{4}\iint_{\Omega}dA=\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1 \int_0^{2\pi} |J|drd\theta$$ and I'm *not really interested in the resolution*.

But *rather* I'm interested in why that region we expressed with polar coordinates would be the same exact region as one described by a circle? Isn't it? It shocks me a little bit since the region $\Omega$ I was integrating over doesn't actually represent the star-shaped region but instead it represents a circle, but I do get the area of the star-shaped region and not the one of the circle, which I'm guessing it is due to the Jacobian, but this stunned me, is there anything else I can look into to help me see it better?

Comment: Where is that circle that you mention?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos sorry, now should be edited, $0<r<1$, $0<\theta <2\pi$ describes a circle

Comment: Yes, it describes a circle. You want to know why? What has that to do with the computation of that area?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I don't know if those questions are rhethorical or not, I'll take them as if they aren't, yes I would like to know why if both regions (star-shaped and circle) are described with the same $\Omega$, why the integral can give 2 different areas (and yeah I'm sure it has to do with the Jacobian but I can't grasp my head around it)

Comment: They are *not* described the same way. The unit circle is$$\left\{(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)\mid r\in[0,1]\wedge\theta\in[0,2\pi]\right\},$$whereas your region is$$\left\{\left(r\cos^{\color{red}3}\theta,r\sin^{\color{red}3}\theta\right)\mid r\in[0,1]\wedge\theta\in[0,2\pi]\right\}.$$Don't you see a difference?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos then the $\Omega$ I wrote in the post is incorrect? Would make sense to me if it is incorrect then. The thing is that now I realise, I've never seen the $\{(r\sin\theta, r\cos\theta) |\dots\}$ at the beginning, I've always only seen $\{(r,\theta)| \dots\}$

Comment: As you wrote, $\Omega$ describes the unit circle, which is *not* the the region that you are interested in.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos let's consider the very last edit I've made to the lastest comment, you are using the notation $\{(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)|\dots \}$ while I'm using $\{(r,\theta)\in\mathbb{R}^2 |\dots \}$, is there a way to express correctly the region using my notation? Something like $0<r<\sqrt{\frac{1}{(\cos^3\theta+\sin^3\theta)^3}}$, $0<\theta<2\pi$? (it is what you obtain after substituting in $x^{2/3}+y^{2/3}=1$). *Note: I know it wouldn't be an easier method to integrate it with this, but I want to make sure I've understood it correctly*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145566/discussion-between-jose-carlos-santos-and-xetrez).

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the comments, the transformation $$x = r \cos^3 \theta, \quad y = r \sin^3 \theta \tag{1}$$ is not a cartesian-to-polar transformation.  It should be obvious why:  if $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ is a circle in the Cartesian plane, then in the $(r,\theta)$ coordinate system this relation becomes
$$r^2 (\cos^6 \theta + \sin^6 \theta) = 1. \tag{2}$$  Application of additional trigonometric identities results in the equivalent expression
$$\cos 4\theta = \frac{8-5r^2}{3r^2}. \tag{3}$$  This does not even remotely resemble a unit circle, which in polar coordinates would simply be $r = 1$.

What does end up being a circle in the $(r,\theta)$ system specified by $(1)$, is the equation $$x^{2/3} + y^{2/3} = 1. \tag{4}$$  That is, after all, precisely why we chose to use that transformation:  it allows us to map the shape described by $(4)$ into a circle in the new coordinate system, which is then easily integrated.  But as the Jacobian is nontrivial, this also means the differential area element in the new system is not constant with respect to its coordinates, just like how in the usual polar system, the differential area element is proportional to its distance from the origin; i.e. $$dA = dx \, dy = r \, dr \, d\theta.$$

Geometrically, another way to conceptualize the effect of such a transformation $(1)$, is that it changes the boundary of the curve but also the way the region in inside the curve is "weighted" when its area is calculated.

Comment: can you please check out the comment I've just posted in my post? It's related to your post as well and it would clear me out all my doubts.

Comment: **Edit: Nevermind just found an issue**